# Sort a list of tuples by the first element of the tuple without removing duplicates

Tags: python, list, duplicates, tuples

I have a list of tuples where the first element in each tuple is an integer and the second is another type of object. I need to sort this list, which usually isn't a problem. I understand that the sorted() function sorts by the first element normally, but here when it finds duplicates of the first element, it compares the second element of those tuples, which are not numbers, so I get the error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Vertex' and 'Vertex'
```

Here is what my list looks like:

```
[(80579631349660530, <__main__.Vertex object at 0x10bf38470>), 
(1, <__main__.Vertex object at 0x10bf384a8>),
(80223811214564369, <__main__.Vertex object at 0x10bf384e0>),
(36780432574096242, <__main__.Vertex object at 0x10bf38518>), 
(43016924753647361, <__main__.Vertex object at 0x10bf38550>), 
(40771682387809932, <__main__.Vertex object at 0x10bf38588>), 
(32096957875591460, <__main__.Vertex object at 0x10bf385c0>),
(1, <__main__.Vertex object at 0x10bf385f8>)]
```

As you can see, two of the tuples have their first element as 1.

Comment: Pass a custom `key` function which *only* returns the first item.

Comment: Try this: let say your list has named 'a', then: ```a.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])```